# How to write unit test case for SaveChangesAsync()

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am writing unit test case for my Entity Framework Core `SaveAsync` method.

```cs
try 
{
    // Here add business logic to insert record in to new database
    var dbObj = new TableName()
                    {
                        Code = 1,
                        Description = "test"
                    };
    _ = _dbContext.TableName.AddAsync(dbObj);
    _ = _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync(context.CancellationToken);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    _logger.LogCritical($"{GetType().Name}:{nameof(Consume)} {ex}");
}

await Task.CompletedTask;
```

I have written unit test case by mocking:

```cs
Mock<MyDbContext> dbContext = new();
var data = return new List<TableName>()
                      {
                          new TableName
                              {
                                  Id = 1,
                                  Description = "test"
                              }
                      };

dbContext.Setup(r => r.TableName).ReturnsDbSet(data);
dbContext.Setup(r => r.SaveChangesAsync(It.IsAny<CancellationToken>())).ReturnsAsync(1);

// Check that each method was only called once.
//dbContext.Verify(x => x.TableName.Add(It.IsAny<TableName>()), Times.Once());
dbContext.Verify(x => x.SaveChangesAsync(It.IsAny<CancellationToken>()), Times.Once());
```

Below is what I get as a result

> Moq.MockException : Expected invocation on the mock once, but was 0 times

While debugging the test case, I am getting the below.

Comment: Do you intend to discard the tasks returned by the async methods rather than awaiting them?

Comment: Updated the question ...i am added  await Task.CompletedTask; after my try catch block

Comment: _What_ exactly are you testing? And you can only verify _after_ you acted. Do you?

Comment: That’s not how await works. I suggest you read up on it

Comment: This s my code in my consume method...my consume method listen to an event and Just save a record in to the table . Here I am trying to mock the db and need to prove that a record will get saved in my db... writing nunit test case which is added in the question

Comment: @JonasHøgh can you suggest some readings

Comment: The error indicates the SaveChangesAsync method with the parameter you passed into it has not been excuted

Answer (score 0):

Firstly,add await into try catch block.otherwise it would not catch excption

```
try 
{
    // Here add business logic to insert record in to new database
    var dbObj = new TableName()
                    {
                        Code = 1,
                        Description = "test"
                    };
    _ = await _dbContext.TableName.AddAsync(dbObj);
    _ = await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync(context.CancellationToken);
}

//remove this line

    await Task.CompletedTask;
```

The [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/task-asynchronous-programming-model#BKMK_WhatHappensUnderstandinganAsyncMethod) related with Asynchronous programming

And you could check the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/fundamentals/testing/mocking?redirectedfrom=MSDN#testing-non-query-scenarios) related with testing non query scenarios

I tried as below:

Assuming a controller:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("Id,Name")] SomeEntity someEntity)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                try
                {
                    await _context.AddAsync(someEntity);
                    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {

                }
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }
            return View(someEntity);
        }
```

Test:

```
public class UnitTest1
    {
        [Fact]
        public  async Task Test1()
        {
            var mockset = new Mock<DbSet<SomeEntity>>();
            var mockdbcontext = new Mock<WebApplication8Context>(new DbContextOptions<WebApplication8Context>() );
            mockdbcontext.Setup(x=>x.SomeEntity).Returns(mockset.Object);
            var a = mockdbcontext.Object;

            var controller = new SomeEntitiesController(mockdbcontext.Object);

            await controller.Create(new SomeEntity() { Name = "someName" });

            
            mockdbcontext.Verify(x => x.SaveChangesAsync(default(CancellationToken)), Times.Once);
        }
    }
```

Result:

[image]